# gulp.src() or it's alternative outside the gulp task

Tags: node.js, gulp

Let me to start from the problem. In my `gulpfile.js`, I need to get some files in multiple paths, collect some info about this files (e. g. file names) and write this info to file (suppose, to `info.json`). Then, `info.json` will be used in the gulp tasks.

This question about first step - getting files in multiple watchable directories. It is simple via `gulp.src([/* paths array */])`, but I can not do whatever I what inside pipeline as below:

```
gulp.task('parse files collection', callback =>{
    return gulp.src([/* array of the paths */]).
        .pipe// Now I need to do collect some info about this files, e. g. file names
        // and write this info to file
})
```

So I need to do above actions inside some function, not inside gulp task. But I if so, I can not use `gulp.src()` inside this function to collect the files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [node-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)

Actually this is underlying of gulp.src()

Comment: It will be the solution! Thank you for the answer!